# How do I create functions for diffrent turtles on netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo, We are told to rotate our First name in a circle and within that, your last name in a smaller circle. How do I make the function only call one turtle

heres my code:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  [
   set color green ;
   set xcor (min-pxcor - 5);
   set ycor 5;
   set heading 0;
   set label "George";
   set label-color red;
   set size 15;
   pendown
  ]
  create-turtles 1
  [
   set color red;
   set xcor (min-pxcor - 1)
   set ycor 5;
   set heading 0;
   set label "Makunde";
   set label-color green;
   set size 15;
   pendown
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles
  [
   fd (pi * (max-pycor - 2) / 100) / 32
   rt 0.125
  ]
tick
end
```

Comment: have a look at `one-of` in the Netlogo dictionary - I am not entirely clear what you want to do, but that is likely to get you the next step

Comment: another possibility is to use the turtle's `who` number. the first turtle you make is `turtle 0`, the second is `turtle 1`, and so forth. and you can, for example, `ask turtle 0 [ ... ]`